# PDF ToUnicode CMap: multicharacter and non-BMP mappings

Tags: pdf, fonts, character-encoding, pdf-generation, postscript

Imagine we have two *bfchar* mappings:

```
beginbfchar
  <1E> <00660069>
endbfchar

beginbfchar
  <358A> <D842DFB7> 
endbfchar
```

Obviously the 1st one should be interpreted as 2 characters mapping U+0066 U+0069.

I thought the same logic must be applied to the 2nd range, but Adobe's [ToUnicode Mapping File Tutorial](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/5411.ToUnicode.pdf#page=9) on page 5 gives exactly this example explaining non-BMP codepoints mappings. And even worse, I suspect that non-BMP mappings can also be multicharacter.

The question is: what is the exact rule to make difference between BMP codepoints multicharacter mapping and non-BMP mappings for the example above.

Please refer to Adobe spec, tutorial or recommendation if possible.

Comment: I'm not sure but are you asking for how you have to handle [surrogate](https://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-2) pairs?

Comment: @JanSlabon No. Are non-BMP mappings used for surrogate pairs only?

Comment: The other way around, surrogate pairs are used for non-BMP mappings.

Comment: @mkl thank you. this answers my question.